# run a function after checkbox checked and pushed submit button with jquery

Tags: jquery, function, checkbox, submit

i'm trying to run a function after checkbox checked and pushed submit button with jquery

this is what i have:

```
 <form name="select">
       <label for="Genre"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="Genre">Genre</label>
       <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="submit">      
 </form>
```

this is my function:

```
function myFunction() {

    $("input [id=Genre] [checked]").each(
        function() {
            alert("genre is checked");  
        }

    );  
}
```

any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/. Spaces in selectors mean something.

Comment: i don't think you can use   $("input [id=Genre] [checked]") instead use $("input[id='Genre']:checked")

Comment: thx, $("input[id='Genre']:checked") is working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select by ID you can just use:

```
$('#Genre')
```

If you want to select all checkboxes then you can just:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]')
```

If you want to select a checked checkbox you can use:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
```

If you want to do something WHEN someone checks a checkbox you need to add an event listener:

```
$('#Genre').bind('click', function() {
   // do something when checkbox with ID Genre is clicked

   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      // do something when the checkbox is checked
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#formid').submit(function(){
$('#genre:checked').each(function()
      {
         alert('checked');
      })
 });
```

Comment: He wants to iterate on checked checkboxes when the submit button is clicked, not do something when the checkbox's state changes

Answer (score 0):

Try using : `$('input#Genre :checked')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input#Genre :checked").each(
    function() {
        alert("genre is checked");
    }
);
```

Comment: was missing the closing `);`, fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

The way you attach your function to the submit button is not the "jQuery" way.

Try this :

```js
$('input[value=submit]').on('click', myFunction);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5jj8e/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#formid').submit(function(){
   if($('#Genre').is(':checked')){
    return true;
}
alert('Not checked');
return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML give the **value** in radio button

```
<form name="select">
       <label for="Genre"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="Genre" value="Genre1" >Genre</label>
       <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="submit">      
 </form>
```

And jquery should be

```
function myFunction() {

    if($("input[id='Genre']:checked").length==0)
    {
        alert("genre is checked");  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's check selector: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/