# Run a function when submitting a form failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I have the following set of checkboxes in a webpage

```
<form id="tagselect" action="">
<input id="tag" type="checkbox" value="*">Show all</input>
<input id="tag" type="checkbox" value=".Name1">Name1</input>
<input id="tag" type="checkbox" value=".Name2">Name2</input>
<input type="button" value="submit"></input>
</form>
```

I want to make it so a function runs either when the submit button is pressed, or remove the submit button and make it so it runs any time any checkbox is changed.

I have tried pretty much every different way to achieve this as recommended in this old question here:
[run a function after checkbox checked and pushed submit button with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549205/run-a-function-after-checkbox-checked-and-pushed-submit-button-with-jquery)
along with a few different tweaks of them just o a random hunch, and I cannot get ANYTHING to happen when a checkbox is checked except the checkmark appearing. I tested with a simple:

```
alert("This is working");
```

and it worked fine when it was just running in a script block with no conditions, but as soon as i put it in the middle of some script to make it run when a checkbox is checked or a button is pushed, the alert won't appear no matter what.

A few of the things I've tried:

```
<script>
$("input[id='tag']:checked").each(
    function() {
        alert("This is working");
    }
);
</script>
```

Attempt 2:

```
<script>
$("input#tag :checked").each(
    function() {
        alert("This is working");
    }
);  
</script>
```

Attempt 3:

```
<script>
$('#tagselect').submit(function(){
$('#tag:checked').each(function()
      {
         alert("This is working");
      })
 });
</script>
```

Attempt 4:

```
<script>
$('input[value=submit]').on('click', myFunction);
```

Then this in either a new script block or the same script block(tried both):

```
function myFunction() {
alert("This is working");
}
</script>
```

I also tried that same myFunction, but with

```
onclick="myFunction()"
```

added to the submit button html

Absolutely nothing visibly happened besides the button clicking or the checkboxes checking on any of these runs.

I have also tried putting all the scripts together in the head, together in the body, separately around where they are going to be used, ad i have triple checked spelling and capitalization is consistent in the actual copies. I have removed the submit button and tried some of these without it. I have tried switching browsers in case it was a compatibility issue. I don't know enough about JS to even know where to start researching what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I did add jQuery...and i don't know how to add a JS fiddle, but it's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you don't get it working. One thing is, you might need to `preventDefault` action on the form elements. And there's no `</input>`. Learn it correctly. Have the sample script below.

So the things you need to note:

1. Prevent the default event: `event.preventDefault();`.
2. No `</input>` tags.
3. Encapsulate everything inside `$(document).ready()` event.
4. The type of the `<input />` should be `submit` and not `button`.
5. Your HTML contains duplicated `id`s. IDs are meant to be unique, else it doesn't work.

Those scripts you tried are loaded just once. To alert when the button is checked, you need to set a condition like this:

```
$(function () {
  $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
      alert("Yay! Checked");
  });
});
```

And finally to run a function on form's submit, you need to use the following code:

```
$("#tagselect").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("Submitted");
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
      alert("Yay! Checked");
  });
  $("#tagselect").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Submitted");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="tagselect" action="">
  <input name="tag" type="checkbox" value="*" /> Show all
  <input name="tag" type="checkbox" value=".Name1" /> Name1
  <input name="tag" type="checkbox" value=".Name2" /> Name2
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: @Gacci Thanks for letting me know. I have added that! `:)`

Comment: This worked for me, thank you, so far everything is now working exactly as I intended. I had actually tried without the </input> too but i copied the section from somewhere and that version had those in it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your check boxes don't have listeners. If you want your form being submitted on clicking the checkboxes, the listeners should be attached to the checkboxes. Else if you want the form being submitted on clicking submit then the event is attached to the form. What you have does not show you attached any listeners to checkboxes
Then, ID should be a unique identifier, you can't give more than one element the same id.

Finally, If you include jQuery library, then this should work.

```
JQuery("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(event){
//your code here!
});
```